# Two C file with same variable name but one of type static and one Global, though GCC didn't gave error

Tags: c

**======> file1.c <=========**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int var = 10;

void sub();

int main()

{


  printf("\n value of var(in file1) :: %d",var); 

  printf("\n Address of var(in file1) :: %p",&var);

  sub();


  return 0;

}
```

**=======> file2.c <==========**

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int var = 20;

void sub()

{

  printf("\n value of var(in file2) :: %d",var);

  printf("\n Address of var(in file2) :: %p",&var);

}
```

**command used to build ----**

```
gcc   file1.c    file2.c    -o    objectFile
```

**command used to run ------**

```
    ./objectFile
```

**output received --------**

```
value of var(in file1) :: 10
Address of var(in file1) :: 0x601040
value of var(in file2) :: 20
Address of var(in file2) :: 0x601038
```

**Query ::**

How GCC compiler resolve the name conflict while linking ????
Do compiler add any prefix for both variable to differentiate between 2 variable ???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe that's just a typo `stdio.h`

Comment: yes, sorry . I just edited that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How GCC compiler resolve the name conflict while linking?

With only one global variable, there is no conflict for the linker to resolve. The fact that the `static` variable shares the same name with a global variable does not matter, because static variables are invisible to the linker.

The same name of a static variable or a static function could be used in several translation units without causing linking conflicts. Marking variables `static` makes them "local" to the translation unit in which they are defined. Other translation units cannot access these variables, giving programmers a degree of isolation between their translation units. That is why the two `var`s in your scenario are located at different addresses.

Answer (score 0):

(stdio.c should be stdio.h)

`static int var = 20;` has file scope and is only visible in file2.

`var` of file 2 is only valid in file 2. There is no conflict.

If you do something like this instead:

```
static int w1 = 10;
void sub2() {
    int w1 = 20; //this causes shadowing. Inside sub2 w1 ==20 now.
}
```